# Clarification on application of Central Limit Theorem in Example from *Rice*

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

My question comes from an example in *Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis 3rd edition* by John Rice. The following screenshot is the discussion of the example:

[image]

My question is with the interpretation of the final answer. The example says that: "The probability is rather small, so the fairness of the coin is called into question."

My take on this is, if we are evaluating the probability of a deviation as extreme or more extreme than 60, wouldn't we want a smaller probability (if we are assuming our coin is fair)? Wouldn't we want the probability of anything deviating from our "fair" evaluation of 50 to be small? Now imagining the distribution of head flips visually in terms of a normal distribution, I could see what is being meant. But I'm finding a disconnect in the understanding.

Comment: The idea is that the probability that you would see 60 or more heads in 100 flips of a fair coin is low, so because you actually did see 60 heads, it appears unlikely that the coin is actually fair. Your question is really only about hypothesis testing and does not really have anything to do with CLT.

Comment: Got it, well reason I put CLT is because the example is coming from a chapter revolving around the CLT. Thanks for the help.

Comment: CLT enters because CLT implies BINOM(100, 1/2) is approximately NORM(50, 5), used go get $P(X \ge 60) \approx 0.0288.$ From R, _exact_ value is $P(X\ge 60) = 0.02844397$ from `1 - pbinom(59, 100, .5)` which returns $0.02844397.$ // If coin is fair it would be rare to get 60 or more Heads in 100 tosses.

Comment: Yes, CLT is being used in the calculation, but the question is really about the interpretation of a hypothesis test, which would be the same if they were using the exact binomial distribution instead.